# Tailwindcss default hide left side drawer on mobile but show when toggle button click

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am a bit struggling draw show and hide.

1. On desktop, drawer will show as default. User can show and hide(not entirely hide but show icon only) when button click.
2. On mobile, want to hide drawer as default. User can show and hide(hide entirely)

Current div css as follow, I can achieved 1.

On mobile, drawer is hide as default but when user click the button, drawer does not show.

I know that it is because of the hidden md:block.

How can I show the drawer on mobile when user click the button.

```
<div
  className={`flex flex-col h-full p-0 text-white bg-primary shadow-inner transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out drawer drawer-mobile ${
    colapse ? "w-12" : "w-[18rem]"
  } overflow-y-auto hidden md:block`}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed as follow and detect the browser and setColapse true if browser is true.

```
<div
className={`flex flex-col h-full p-0 text-white bg-primary shadow-inner 
transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out drawer drawer-mobile ${
colapse ? "w-12 hidden md:block" : "w-[18rem]"
} overflow-y-auto`}
>
```